# How can I split the User name and password group in the register page?

Tags: forms, users

I want to split the User name and password group in the register page into separate fields but they are wrapped into `"<div id="user_register_form"><h1>Register</h1>..."`

The open "div" is set as a prefix on the account name field but I can not find the close div.

Comment: Found it. A suffix with a close div is added to the submit button.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Account field split](https://www.drupal.org/project/account_field_split) module for this:

> About
>
> Currently the draggable field "Username and password" on user profile
> mashes together:
>
> ```
> Username
> Current password
> E-mail address
> Change Password
> Roles
> Status
> Notify user about new account (when admin create new account)
> ```
>
> This module aims to split "Username and password" into standalone
> fields for site builders who want to manage that fields separately.